Solidity Contract Error: "call to SimpleStorage.people errored: invalid opcode"
I'm encountering an issue with my Solidity contract and could use some help debugging it. I have a simple contract named SimpleStorage that includes a struct People and an array people to store instances of this struct. The contract has a function addPeople to add a new person to the array.
However, when I try to call the addPeople function, I receive the following error message: "call to SimpleStorage.people errored: invalid opcode". I'm not sure what's causing this error.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

contract SimpleStorage {
    uint favoriteNumber;

    struct People {
        uint favoriteNumber;
        string name;
    }

    People[] public people;

    function addPeople(string memory _name, uint _favoriteNumber) public {
        People memory newPeople = People(_favoriteNumber, _name);
        people.push(newPeople);
    }
}

I've tried increasing the gas limit, but that didn't solve the issue. Can someone please help me understand what's causing this error and how I can fix it?

I see no problem from my end. Your code works fine.
Try cleaning , rebooting or using different tools. Remix is fast, easy, reliable and powerful for learning and trying new things

Which network are you using? How are you calling addPeople?

It worked on my side, as you can see in the picture below. First, try refreshing your browser and then compile and deploy the code. If the problem persists, switch to a different browser; that should resolve the issue.

